# Job created by CreateMigrationJobEncrypted method fails to read xml metadata files

Tags: c#, .net, sharepoint, import, migration

I am trying to get job created by Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Site.CreateMigrationJobEncrypted to read my metadata files. I have tried various ways but nothing works. Let me describe them and various errors I'm getting.

### Method 1:

I provision containers for data & metadata and a queue (queue stores progress messages):

```cs
// ... getting context and such first

ClientResult<ProvisionedMigrationContainersInfo> containers =     clientContext.Site.ProvisionMigrationContainers();
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
ClientResult<ProvisionedMigrationQueueInfo> queue = clientContext.Site.ProvisionMigrationQueue();
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

Then I get encryption key from the returned containers structure.

```cs
var encryptOption = new EncryptionOption
{
    AES256CBCKey = containers?.Value.EncryptionKey,
};
```

Then I upload data files (they do not matter ATM as I never reach the point that they get used).

Then I upload metadata files to the container which should store metadata for import job. I also use `encryptOption.AES256CBCKey` to encrypt them, I follow AES CBC 256 standard, and I generate `IV` using `System.Security.Cryptography.Aes`. Then I add metadata for the generated blobs (each blob represents one xml metadata file). Metadata I add only sets `IV` on a blob. I also create the needed snapshots. Here's the part which sets `IV`.

```cs
// ... other things

// Convert IV to a string format (e.g., Base64) for storing as metadata
string ivBase64 = Convert.ToBase64String(iv);

// Set the IV as metadata
IDictionary<string, string> metadata = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
    { "IV", ivBase64 }
};
blobClient.SetMetadata(metadata);

// 3 Create snapshot for all files
blobClient.CreateSnapshot();
```

Then I create job and execute it:

```cs
var jobReadInfo = clientContext.Site.CreateMigrationJobEncrypted(
  Guid.Parse(targetWebId), // gWebId
  containers.Value.DataContainerUri, // azureContainerSourceUri
  containers.Value.MetadataContainerUri, // azureContainerManifestUri
  queue.Value.JobQueueUri, //azureQueueReportUri
  encryptOption);

clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

When I read the log generated by the job I get this kind of errors (a bit different each call):

```
[1/16/2024 7:36:58 AM] Start Time: 1/16/2024 7:36:58 AM. 
[1/16/2024 7:36:58 AM] Correlation Id: 805102a1-c02f-7000-f07b-b7c87b4b59b8  
[1/16/2024 7:36:58 AM] [Progress] Initializing Import. 
[1/16/2024 7:36:58 AM] [Progress] Downloaded SystemData.xml: SnapShotTime == ; MD5 == b7y78P4VFYpmAW7Tx79NfA==; Size == 400 bytes 
[1/16/2024 7:36:58 AM] [FatalError] [-2146232000] [System.Xml.XmlException] [Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.]  
[1/16/2024 7:36:58 AM] [Debug]    at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(Exception e) 
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseRootLevelWhitespace() 
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseDocumentContent() 
   at System.Xml.XsdValidatingReader.Read() 
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.SPImport.EnsureVersion() 
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.SPImport.Run()
```

or

```
[1/16/2024 7:40:11 AM] Start Time: 1/16/2024 7:40:11 AM. 
[1/16/2024 7:40:11 AM] Correlation Id: af5102a1-2057-8000-099d-2916a2a0a0a5  
[1/16/2024 7:40:11 AM] [Progress] Initializing Import. 
[1/16/2024 7:40:11 AM] [Progress] Downloaded SystemData.xml: SnapShotTime == ; MD5 == Kej88c87xr7WGI1nYq9uxA==; Size == 400 bytes 
[1/16/2024 7:40:11 AM] [FatalError] [-2146232000] [System.Xml.XmlException] [Invalid character in the given encoding. Line 1, position 1.]  
[1/16/2024 7:40:11 AM] [Debug]    at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(Exception e) 
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.InvalidCharRecovery(Int32& bytesCount, Int32& charsCount) 
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.GetChars(Int32 maxCharsCount) 
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ReadData() 
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.SwitchEncoding(Encoding newEncoding) 
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseXmlDeclaration(Boolean isTextDecl) 
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Read() 
   at System.Xml.XsdValidatingReader.Read() 
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.SPImport.EnsureVersion() 
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.SPImport.Run() 
[1/16/2024 7:40:11 AM] [Progress] Import did not complete. 
[1/16/2024 7:40:11 AM] Finish Time: 1/16/2024 7:40:11 AM. 
[1/16/2024 7:40:11 AM] Duration: 00:00:00 
[1/16/2024 7:40:11 AM] Byte imported: 0.00 at 0.00 bytes per second 
[1/16/2024 7:40:11 AM] Total Processed Objects: 0 
[1/16/2024 7:40:11 AM] Finished with 0 warnings. 
[1/16/2024 7:40:11 AM] Finished with 1 errors.
```

This looks like the import job is trying to read the encrypted by me files as plain text when parsing its XML. It should decrypt them first but it does not.

### Method 2:

Now, I am thinking that maybe I don't need to encrypt these files. I dropped the encryption of xml metadata files. But I kept the rest the same. So I still call `CreateMigrationJobEncrypted` method and provide `encryptionOption` to it provided by the generated containers variable (`containers?.Value.EncryptionKey`).

The error I'm getting now is:

```
[1/16/2024 6:54:53 AM] Start Time: 1/16/2024 6:54:52 AM. 
[1/16/2024 6:54:53 AM] Correlation Id: 174f02a1-209c-7000-f07b-bf1736dce42f  
[1/16/2024 6:54:53 AM] [Progress] Initializing Import. 
[1/16/2024 6:54:53 AM] [Error] Unable to download SystemData.xml with exception 'Must specify IV in Manifest or blob metadata' 
[1/16/2024 6:54:53 AM] [Error] Unable to download Requirements.xml with exception 'Must specify IV in Manifest or blob metadata' 
[1/16/2024 6:54:53 AM] [Warning] Import requirement file Requirements.xml was not found no verifications ran. 
[1/16/2024 6:54:53 AM] [Error] Unable to download ExportSettings.xml with exception 'Must specify IV in Manifest or blob metadata' 
[1/16/2024 6:54:53 AM] [FatalError] [-2147024894] [System.IO.FileNotFoundException] [Missing Export Settings file stream]  
[1/16/2024 6:54:53 AM] [Debug]    at Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.SPImport.DeserializeExportSettings() 
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.SPImport.Run() 
[1/16/2024 6:54:53 AM] [Progress] Import did not complete. 
[1/16/2024 6:54:53 AM] Finish Time: 1/16/2024 6:54:53 AM. 
[1/16/2024 6:54:53 AM] Duration: 00:00:00 
[1/16/2024 6:54:53 AM] Byte imported: 0.00 at 0.00 bytes per second 
[1/16/2024 6:54:53 AM] Total Processed Objects: 0 
[1/16/2024 6:54:53 AM] Finished with 1 warnings. 
[1/16/2024 6:54:53 AM] Finished with 4 errors. 
:54 AM] Total Processed Objects: 0 
[1/16/2024 6:53:54 AM] Finished with 0 warnings. 
[1/16/2024 6:53:54 AM] Finished with 1 errors.
```

Which makes me think, that I need to encrypt these files when using `CreateMigrationJobEncrypted` method.

### Method 3:

I've decided to use `CreateMigrationJob` method instead of `CreateMigrationJobEncrypted`. It does not need `encryptOption` argument. I did not encrypt xml metadata files and when I attempted to created job with this method it failed (on `ExecuteQuery`):

```cs
var jobReadInfo = clientContext.Site.CreateMigrationJob(
  Guid.Parse(targetWebId), // gWebId (same as clientContext.Web.Id)
  containers.Value.DataContainerUri, // azureContainerSourceUri
  containers.Value.MetadataContainerUri, // azureContainerManifestUri
  queue.Value.JobQueueUri);
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();  // throws exception
```

Exception thrown is:

```
Error: Invalid use of SPOContainer.
```

I can only assume that these containers which are created for the migration require encryption as they provide us back encryption key. This method could potentially be used with self provided not encrypted containers. I did not try this way.

### Conclusion:

I am not sure what to do with this except of trying my own containers. But I would like to avoid it.

Could someone here point me in the right direction?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have realised I added `IV` to the beginning of every file I encrypted. It is not needed as it is added to the blob's metadata. With it removed "Method 1" I described works now.